# Is it possible to read data from shinyWidgets::noUiSliderInput() while the slider is still dragged?

Tags: r, shiny, nouislider

Is it possible to continuously keep track of where the slider is, 
even before the dragging was finished and the mouse click was released?

**Minimal example:**
(Notice how the slider value is updated only after the dragging was finished)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    noUiSliderInput(
      inputId = "the_slider", label = NULL, 
      min = 0, max = 10, step = 1, value = 5, 
      behaviour =  c("snap")
    ),
    textOutput("slider_value")
  ), 
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$slider_value <- renderText(input$the_slider)
  }
)
```

*Edit:*
The final goal is that the value of `input$the_slider` will be updated continuously, and not just after the mouse is released.

In the screenshot below the slider is on **7**, but its value is still **5**, because I haven't released the mouse yet.

[image]

Comment: please explain more. and what is your final goal? I mean what is in your mind?

Comment: The final goal is that the value of `input$the_slider` will be updated continuously, and not just after the mouse is released. See edit to question above

Comment: It's possible, please open an issue on GitHub and I'll look into it. https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets

Comment: Thanks @Victorp! Really appreciate it. Just opened one: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/121

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by @Victorp [here](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues/121). Thank you!

To enable this new feature install shinyWidgets from Github and use the argument `update_on = "change"`.